# Why my screen automatically zooms? How to stop it?

Tags: xubuntu

I am in Xubuntu. Sometimes, when I use Android Studio and suddenly change my "activity". I meant whenever I visit Android Studio to Chrome using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> then my screen automatically zoom. Here how it looks whenever it automatically zoom.

[image: screen]

It's totally annoying how to stop this kind of behavior?

[image: screen]

I remember that, I had seen once that when I start laptop then a text appear on right top which say "Sticky key started" or something just like this. I don't remember the text correctly.

```
istiak@istiak-ThinkPad-X220:~$ locate sticky
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1515/share/icons/Yaru/16x16/legacy/sticky_zoom.svg
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Yaru/16x16/legacy/sticky_zoom.svg
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20/14/usr/share/icons/breeze/actions/16/sticky_zoom.svg
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20/14/usr/share/icons/breeze-dark/actions/16/sticky_zoom.svg
/usr/share/help/C/gnome-help/a11y-stickykeys.page
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-84/tools/testing/selftests/net/forwarding/bridge_sticky_fdb.sh
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-27/tools/testing/selftests/net/forwarding/bridge_sticky_fdb.sh
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-34/tools/testing/selftests/net/forwarding/bridge_sticky_fdb.sh
```

> gedit /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515/share/icons/Yaru/16x16/legacy/sticky_zoom.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   height="16"
   width="16"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg2041"
   sodipodi:docname="sticky_zoom.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)">
  <metadata
     id="metadata2047">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs2045" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1294"
     inkscape:window-height="704"
     id="namedview2043"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.99999999"
     inkscape:cx="-178.09447"
     inkscape:cy="6"
     inkscape:window-x="72"
     inkscape:window-y="27"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg2041">
    <inkscape:grid
       type="xygrid"
       id="grid2676" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <path
     style="color:#000000;font-weight:400;line-height:normal;font-family:sans-serif;font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-position:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-alternates:normal;font-feature-settings:normal;text-indent:0;text-align:start;text-decoration:none;text-decoration-line:none;text-decoration-style:solid;text-decoration-color:#000000;text-transform:none;text-orientation:mixed;white-space:normal;shape-padding:0;overflow:visible;opacity:0.7;isolation:auto;mix-blend-mode:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
     d="M 7.5,1 A 6.508,6.508 0 0 0 1,7.5 c 0,3.584 2.916,6.5 6.5,6.5 1.612224,0 3.087362,-0.592853 4.224609,-1.568359 l 2.921875,2.921875 0.707032,-0.707032 -2.921875,-2.921875 C 13.407147,10.587362 14,9.1122237 14,7.5 14,3.916 11.084,1 7.5,1 Z m 0,1.0390625 c 3.022,0 5.460938,2.4389375 5.460938,5.4609375 0,3.022 -2.438938,5.460938 -5.460938,5.460938 A 5.454,5.454 0 0 1 2.0390625,7.5 C 2.0390625,4.478 4.479,2.0390625 7.5,2.0390625 Z"
     id="path2035-9"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  <path
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="path2035"
     overflow="visible"
     style="color:#000000;font-weight:400;line-height:normal;font-family:sans-serif;font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-position:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-alternates:normal;font-feature-settings:normal;text-indent:0;text-align:start;text-decoration:none;text-decoration-line:none;text-decoration-style:solid;text-decoration-color:#000000;text-transform:none;text-orientation:mixed;white-space:normal;shape-padding:0;overflow:visible;isolation:auto;mix-blend-mode:normal;fill:#c8c4b7;fill-opacity:1"
     d="M 7.5,1 A 6.508,6.508 0 0 0 1,7.5 C 1,11.084 3.916,14 7.5,14 11.084,14 14,11.084 14,7.5 14,3.916 11.084,1 7.5,1 Z m 0,1.04 c 3.022,0 5.46,2.438 5.46,5.46 0,3.022 -2.438,5.46 -5.46,5.46 A 5.454,5.454 0 0 1 2.039,7.5 c 0,-3.022 2.44,-5.46 5.461,-5.46 z" />
  <path
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="path2037"
     overflow="visible"
     style="color:#000000;font-weight:400;line-height:normal;font-family:sans-serif;font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-position:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-alternates:normal;font-feature-settings:normal;text-indent:0;text-align:start;text-decoration:none;text-decoration-line:none;text-decoration-style:solid;text-decoration-color:#000000;text-transform:none;text-orientation:mixed;white-space:normal;shape-padding:0;overflow:visible;isolation:auto;mix-blend-mode:normal;fill:#c8c4b7;fill-rule:evenodd;fill-opacity:1"
     d="m 11.853,11.146 -0.707,0.708 3.5,3.5 0.707,-0.708 z"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1;vector-effect:none;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
     id="path2707"
     sodipodi:type="arc"
     sodipodi:cx="7.5"
     sodipodi:cy="7.5"
     sodipodi:rx="5.5"
     sodipodi:ry="5.5"
     sodipodi:start="0"
     sodipodi:end="6.2319424"
     sodipodi:open="true"
     d="M 13,7.5 A 5.5,5.5 0 0 1 7.5704571,12.999549 5.5,5.5 0 0 1 2.0018052,7.6409026 5.5,5.5 0 0 1 7.288675,2.0040613 a 5.5,5.5 0 0 1 5.704106,5.214226" />
  <path
     style="fill:none;stroke:#46a926;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="M 12.500107,5.9999998 7.5001068,11 l -3,-3.0000002"
     id="path8695"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Do you have any assistive settings or programs running that use these hot keys?

Comment: @music2myear I don't know. I have checked them. But couldn't find one